# How to cite articles from a well known website

Tags: bibtex, natbib, urls

I would like to cite articles and the specific authors from well known websites. My problem is that I would also like to include the website info in the citation. For example I am citing an article from Surfing Magazine but the article was only published online and not in the magazine. Alternatively, I am looking to cite an article from surfline.com by a named author but I would like surfline.com to show up in the citation alone and not just included in the url portion of the citation.

My code is as follows:

For the online references I used the following format in my .bib file (Cite.bib)

```
 @MISC{maldives,
   author =       "Connoly, Darlene",
   title =        "Controversy in the Maldives",
   editor =       "Surfline.com",
   month =        "August",
   year =         "2012",
   url =          "\url{http://www.surfline.com/surf-news/maldives-surf-access-controversy-update_75296/ }",
   note =         "[Online; posted 27-August-2012]",
 }

 @MISC{mull,
   author =       "Mull, Jeff",
   title =        "Maldives Controversy",
   editor =       "Surfing Magazine",
   month =        "September",
   year =         "2010",
   url =          "\url{http://www.surfermag.com/features/maldives-controversy/ }",
   note =         "[Online; posted 13-September-2012]",
 }
```

For the .tex file I am using the following code/packages

```
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \usepackage{url}

 \begin{document}

  text

 \nocite{mull}
 \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
 \bibliography{Cite}

 \end{document}
```

When I try to compile the document using 'pdftexify' I get the following error.

```
Package natbib warning: Citation 'Mull' undefined on input line 373 

[23] [24] [25] (C:\Users\...\LaTex\title.bbl
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@makeother #1->\catcode '#1
                        12\relax
1.12 ...

! ==> Fatal error occured, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on title.log.
texify: pdflatex.exe failed for some reason (see log file)
```

However if I try the same syntax using an @ARTICLE or @BOOK reference from 'Cite.bib,' I do not get the error. I am looking for a way to cite authors of online articles as well as the website they were published on. Any help with this will be really helpful.

Also, if it is not important or not regularly practiced to include the name of the website separately in the citation then I could just omit the editor portion of my @MISC entries. I have tried omitting the editor field but I still get the same error message.

Comment: I thought the `url` field was easier to use: `url = {http://www.surfermag.com/features/maldives-controversy/},`..?  Also, you likely want to `\usepackage{hyperref}` as well.

Answer (score 13):

I have no problems with this slightly changed file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}% <-- useful for embedding external files in the main file
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{maldives,
   author =       {Connoly, Darlene},
   title =        {Controversy in the Maldives},
   editor =       {Surfline.com},
   month =        {August},
   year =         {2012},
   url = {http://www.surfline.com/surf-news/maldives-surf-access-controversy-update_75296/},
   note =         {[Online; posted 27-August-2012]},
 }

@MISC{maldives-alt,
   author =       {Connoly, Darlene},
   title =        {Controversy in the Maldives},
   editor =       {Surfline.com},
   month =        {August},
   year =         {2012},
   note = {\href{http://www.surfline.com/surf-news/maldives-surf-access-controversy-update_75296/}{Surfline.com} {[Online; posted 27-August-2012]}},
 }


@MISC{mull,
   author =       {Mull, Jeff},
   title =        {Maldives Controversy},
   editor =       {Surfing Magazine},
   month =        {September},
   year =         {2010},
   url =          {http://www.surfermag.com/features/maldives-controversy/},
   note =         {[Online; posted 13-September-2012]},
 }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Please refer to \cite{maldives} and \cite{mull}.
And this citation `hides' the link `in the url portion of the citation': \cite{maldives-alt}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the [**biblatex**](http://ctan.org/topic/biblatex) package for that. It supports eprints with easily definable formats. Example:

> biblatex-eprint.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:eccc}{ECCC\addcolon\space\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/#1/}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldAlias{eprint:ECCC}{eprint:eccc}
\begin{document}
\nocite{Voronoi}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> references.bib

```
@article{Voronoi,
    author     = {Micciancio, Daniele  and  Voulgaris, Panagiotis},
    title      = {A Deterministic Single Exponential Time Algorithm for Most Lattice Problems Based on Voronoi Cell Computations},
    journal    = {SIAM Journal on Computing},
    volume     = {42},
    number     = {3},
    year       = 2013,
    pages      = {1364--1391},
    eprint     = {2010/014},
    eprinttype = "eccc",
    adsurl     = {http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2010/014/},
    bibsource  = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
```

arXiv.org is already supported off the hook.

For more information I refer to the biblatex documentation §§ 3.11.7 and 4.11.2.